# @State private variable is immutable

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui, state

I am relatively new to Swift and I am trying to create a View with MapKit.

I have to pass a binding coordinate region to `Map()`, which is stored in a @State variable. However, when I am trying to initialise this variable, the error is **Cannot assign to property: '$region' is immutable**

this is the code:

```swift
struct MapView: View {
  @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
  var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
  }
  init(_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    $region = MKCoordinateRegion( // Cannot assign to property: '$region' is immutable
        center: location,
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
      )
  }
}
```

This is probably an easy fix, but I just couldn't find anything on the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `State(initialValue:)` like this

```
struct MapView: View {
  @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
  var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
  }
  init(_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self._region = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: location,
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
      ))
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Why cant I reference region with $region, but have to use self?

Comment: @NilsSchwebel This is not about `self` but rather about adding an underscore (`_region`). [This](https://jllnmercier.medium.com/swiftui-state-ec5ad8b68457) might help you.